# C# Remove newlines from xml loaded

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have created manually a xml file (DatabaseQueries.xml) as follows (it contains database queries):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Queries>
   <Query1>
            SELECT a, b
            FROM Table1
            WHERE z = 1
   </Query1>

   <Query2>
            SELECT a, b
            FROM Table2
   </Query2>
</Queries>
```

Xml file contains newlines and spaces. Then I add xml file as a resource file in my project and I load it using:

```
XElement resource = XElement.Parse(Properties.Resources.DatabaseQueries);
```

I want to read a query element and convert it to string so I do:

```
resource.Element("Query1").Value
```

But I get a lot of spaces and newlines (\n). Don't worry with spaces but I would like to remove  \n or read the value from xml without containing \n.

I use this string to request values from database later using SqlCommand, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Simply use string replace method to replace "\n" with " " (space).  Remove just the "\n" will give errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expression to replace newlines and repetitive whitespaces with single whitespace:

```
var query1 = Regex.Replace(resource.Element("Query1").Value.Trim(), @"\s+", " ");
```

From [\s Metacharacter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) - a whitespace character can be:

- A space character
- A tab character
- A carriage return character
- A new line character
- A vertical tab character

Output:

```
"SELECT a, b FROM Table1 WHERE z = 1"
```

**NOTE!:** As @Evk stated, this approach is simple, but it also can modify string literals which are used in your queries. I personally haven't seen literals which contain several whitespaces in a row, but you should be aware of this behavior. If you want SQL formatting to be 100% safe, then you should *parse* given SQL query into some syntax tree. And then convert syntax tree to formatted SQL query. You can use tools like [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/tsql) for that, or check some [SQL parsing samples](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/sql_parser.aspx).

Comment: This is very dangerous advice, because it will collapse all whitespace including those inside string literals. For example `WHERE z = 'some<space><space>value'` will become `WHERE z = 'some<space>value'` which will change the meaning of the query.

Comment: @Evk totally agree, though I wouldn't call it *very* dangerous - frankly speaking how many times have you seen `'some<space><space>value'` in SQL queries? I haven't yet :) Solution is simple, but should be used carefully. Ideally you need SQL parser which will build syntax tree

Comment: @Evk I agree, so another solution to get rid of this special case?

Comment: @user1624552 best solution might be not touch those queries at all? Why exactly do you want to remove newlines?